# Pykitti - Getting the Velodyne to Camera Transform

Tags: kitti

I am trying to figure out the API to get the Velodyne to the camera transform, but it looks like the API doesn't expose it. Does anyone know how to get this?

The API only exposes the velodyne to imu, and imu to camera transformations. I tried composing a transform but it doesnt appear to be aligned.